# Should I include User's personal information in the application dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

I am working on the design of a Health/Fitness mobile application whose primary purpose in not constricted to diet/workout and includes various other features (eg: buy health products, book consultations etc.).

Now, coming to my question, is it better to show user's personal information (eg: name, age, profile image)? I am already showing his diet and workout summary for the day.

Comment: It depends too much on the goals, user needs and confidentiality of the app. Can you add some more context to the question? Or maybe some pros and cons with a little background so we can understand the dilemma better.

Answer (score 1):

What value are you creating for the user by displaying this data?
The user probably knows his name and his age etc.

Displaying name + profile picture is pretty common tho, since it creates value for the user.

This might help you understand why displaying profile picture and name for example adds value while displaying age and stuff like this really does not.

[Is there value in a user profile photo for an enterprise app?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75400/is-there-value-in-a-user-profile-photo-for-an-enterprise-app)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it brings much value, since he already knows that. I would only include his picture, for a bit of context.